# amenable groups versus amenable graphs

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, graph-theory, operator-algebras, percolation

In operator algebras, one is often concerned with amenable groups, defined by one of many equivalent conditions.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group#Equivalent_conditions_for_amenability

In percolation theory and "random geometry" one is often concerned with amenable graphs, i.e. those with Cheeger constant $0$.

Are these two notions of amenability related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Let $G$ be a finitely-generated discrete group with finite generating set $S$.  Then $G$ is amenable if and only if the [Cayley graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) of $G$ with respect to $S$ has Cheeger constant 0.  This is known as [Følner's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B8lner_sequence) for amenability.

For example, $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is amenable because the infinite square grid has Cheeger constant zero, and the free group $F_2$ is nonamenable because an infinite $4$-regular tree has positive Cheeger constant.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0086598)

(Chapter 14 of "Harmonic Analysis", edited by Eymard and Pier)